# What does it mean this kanji from Kong movie?

Tags: translation, kanji

sorry, I am curious about what does this Japanese symbol represents.
It's from the latest Kong's movie, Skull Island , and I believe it is taken from the fight airplane of a Japanese pilot during second world war.

[image]

Comment: looks like お or よ + some line

Comment: Hmm doesn't really look like a Japanese (or Chinese) character...

Comment: む or た.  I'm a Tokyo native.  I don't think it's a Japanese letter

Comment: If anything it looks like た to me.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a Japanese symbol or character including Katakana, Hiragana and Kanji. I think that the movie producer wanted to express Japanese exoticism and independently designed the symbol or character similar to Japanese imaginary symbol or character.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the symbol む (mu) which could be relevant if it was on a fighter plane. I say this because 'mu' also 無　which represents 'nothingness' in buddhism seems to me something a Japanese pilot may have written on their plane in the war. Not very well explained but I hope you get my gist.